# What's wrong with my Android Studio gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When I use compile 'xxx' to add a dependencies, an error message as follows:
[image]

what's wrong?
google's support-v4 is ok.
Hope someone can help me...
Thanks.

Comment: The google's support-v4 is downloaded from the local maven (sdk manager). Check the @Cmoaciopm answer

Answer (score 1):

Gradle build system must resolve 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2' from somewhere.

In your case, looks you miss the following configuration in your gradle file.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Then gradle will try to resolve the dependency from MavenCentral.

Of course, you can specify your own repository like this.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a new Android Studio project, it's ok to add dependencies with compile 'xxx'.Maybe the reason is the current project is import from Eclipse.